# git clone only on new change and archive scm

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using to Jenkins to pull code from git in every 10 minutes and then compiling, archiving it for other jobs to clone this workspace. Currently it's pulling code from git every time and then archiving every time.

I want to clone code from git only if there is any new change else it should skip and do not archive the workspace. Which plugin should I use and what configuration I should make in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it sounds like you have a couple things going on here. Here is some possible suggestions that I use to meet similar needs:

1.) If you are only wanting your job to build when there is a change in your source control, in this case GIT, you can use the "Poll SCM" plugin. And then in there set a cron expression to run every 10 minutes.

"Poll SCM" plugin will check source control for any changes and build the job when it finds them. If this works properly your job will not build thus it will not archive anything unnecessarily.

2.) For archiving I would make sure to utilize the "Discard Old Builds" plugin and "Advanced" section to keep a rotation and retention policy for your jobs artifacts.

3.) You state "for other jobs to clone this workspace". Are you actually having other jobs pull in this jobs workspace? Or did you mean copy its artifacts? I ask because the workspace is temporary, in a sense, and you should pull the artifacts. There is a plugin for that as well called "[Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)" that you can use and it allows for various options.

4.) An alternative to "Poll SCM" plugin, if it doesn't work or you do not prefer this, depending on your GIT setup you could also potentially setup a hook that will notify Jenkins of changes. There are various hooks depending on the GIT implementation.

Hope this helps!